# An approximation of rational function with polynomials

Tags: analysis

To compute some asymptotic expression  I need to approximate $$\frac{(x-1)^{r+u}\left((x-1)^{p-r+1}+x^{p-r+1}\right)\left(x^{p-u+1}+(x-1)^{p+u+1}\right)}{\left(x^{2p+2}+(x-1)^{2p+2}\right)}$$ by some polynomial.
Here $x\in(0,0.5)$,$p\geq r,u \geq 0$ some integers.
Somehow Taylor and Lagrange methods don't work to me.  What other methods should I try?

Comment: Have you tried multiplying out the numerator and using the binomial theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just tabulate the values for fixed $r,u$ at the proper points in (0,0.5) you can use a Chebyshev series, which is handy to give a bounded error.  A description is available at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) (also see [Chebyshev nodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes)) and at [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) page 190, which includes C code.